# Active Directory Query returning empty fields where it shouldn't

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I've been facing this problem and it doeen't seems to have an end, hope you can help me.

I'm making an LDAP query against Active Directory within a Powershell script. Getting right to the point this is my code:

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=ivegotusers,DC=global,DC=foo,DC=com")

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

#Write-Host $objSearcher

$colProplist = "name", "sn", "whenCreated", "whenChanged", "createTimeStamp", "modifyTimeStamp", "displayName", "mailNickName"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)
}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults){
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.name
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.displayName;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.sn;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.whenCreated;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.createTimeStamp;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.whenChanged;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.modifyTimeStamp;
    Write-Host "|";
}
```

So we should get as output a line for each query match, being the line format as follows:
name|displayName|sn|whenCreated|createTimeStamp|whenChanged|modifyTimeStamp
right?

**I've checked the data in the ADSI Edit and a lot of users had that data; nevertheless, the output was**

```
name1||sn1||||
name2||sn2||||
name3||sn3||||
name4||sn4||||
name5||sn5||||
```

**for those same users, and there's not a single line that has more than these two fields seted.**

Can anyone help me figuring out what's happening in here?

**Note:** Due to server set-ups, I'm not able to use the ActiveDirectory import on Powershell.

Regards and thanks for your time!
Vlad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got bitten by this one a while ago: you've got two choices:

propertyNames in lower case:

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults){
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.name
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.displayname
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.sn;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.whencreated;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.createtimestamp;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.whenchanged;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.modifytimestamp;
    Write-Host "|";
}
```

or use the .NET collection Item property style syntax:

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults){
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.name
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem["displayName"]
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem.sn;
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem["whenCreated"];
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem["createTimeStamp"];
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem["whenChanged"];
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "|";
    Write-Host -NoNewLine $objItem["modifyTimeStamp"];
    Write-Host "|";
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it worked! Just the all-lower-case properties names did the trick. And of course, I'm now wondering how I managed not to try this before myself. Thank you very much!